# Reputation needed to upvote / downvote

Tags: support, voting, privileges

On Physics Stack Exchange I have 96 reputation points. I'm able to upvote something, but when I tried downvoting a question it said that my vote would be recorded, but not displayed.

Is there a different amount of reputation points needed to downvote than to upvote?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down This should have been easy to find. A post was unrequired. Did you even bother checking your priveleges tab or doing some googling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) - in particular the first section of this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238 which links to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each SE community has its own requirements for upvotes and downvotes. On Physics Stack Exchange, [the minimum rep to downvote is 125](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

For future reference, [check your site's privileges page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to see how many reputation points are required for any specific type of action.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I didn't know about the privileges page.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance Glad I could help. As a side note, if an answer solves your issue [you can mark it as an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/351462).

Comment: Sure, I just did it.  I think I had been a member for a day or two when I asked, so I must have not known about it :)